# Magento Admin - Inventory

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, inventory

When I create many products I wish to add an automatic quantity value and an automatic "In Stock" value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What about mass edit after creation?
- alternative is to change the template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/tab/inventory.phtml`, might be the easiest way.

If you want to do it right, you implement your own admin theme and copy over the template.

Comment: And if I want to add an automatic quantity value and an automatic "In Stock" value just for user role?

Comment: You could check in the template but there must be a better way...

Comment: Yes, example if I want to edit "Status" with an automatic value (enabled), I put $form->addValues(array('status'=> '1')); and it's done. Now I try to add value for Inventory but no result... (www\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php)